# SQL LEFT JOIN not filtering

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I only want to return Events that are found in the Event_site_tag_lu table. But my statement is returning all events.

Events table

```
---+
Id |
---+
1  |  
2  |
3  |
---+
```

Event_site_tag_lu table

```
---------+
event_id |
---------+
1        |
---------+
```

My query is

```
SELECT `id` FROM event LEFT JOIN event_site_tag_lu ON event.id = event_site_tag_lu.event_id
```

Comment: If you want to find only the ones that are found with the join then you don't want a left join but a regular join. Or in this case no join at all, but I assume you want other columns also.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LEFT JOIN ( some databases LEFT OUTER JOIN )returns all rows from the first table in relationship and matching data from other table otherwise null in particular rows for data of second table in relationship

What are you looking for is just JOIN (INNER JOIN) which would just get rows that have match in both tables

```
SELECT event_test.* 
FROM   event_test 
       JOIN log 
         ON event_test.id = log.id
```

Also if you are looking only to events from log not the particular data you could write something like following

```
 SELECT DISTINCT id from log
```

[Jsfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85a21/4)

Answer (score 2):

so you don't really need a left join - inner join will do the work.

Answer (score 1):

Change LEFT to INNER

LEFT JOIN returns all rows from the left table AND the matches

INNER JOIN returns matches only

Comment: What does "and the matches" mean?

Comment: rows where the ID in the events Table(left table) matches the event_id in the Event_site_tag_lu Table(right table).

Comment: LEFT JOIN will also find those matches, but it will also add all of the rows in the events table(left table)